# Random male connectors on my case

Tags: case

I recently purchased a new case, a Fractal Design Define R4.

In hooking this up I'm coming across some curiosities, such as no internal speaker. However the oddest thing is these 3 wires:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/ed0KV9T]

They're male 2 pin connectors. Very odd as most wires on the case are female since the motherboard is male.

I'm guessing they're something to do with fans?

Or are they something else entirely?

What do I do with these wires?

Comment: They look like 2-pin inline fan connectors in what could be 3-pin housings, but the picture is too poor to know for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those connectors are for 3-pin (DC) fans - i.e: the speed is controlled by varying voltage.

The three pins are:

1. GND
2. +12v (or lower to reduce fan speed)
3. Tachometer (unused, or used to sense the fan speed) - unpopulated in this case

More and more fans are 4-pin (PWM) which take a fixed +12v supply with an additional input signal to control the fan's speed.

1. GND
2. +12v
3. Tachometer (used to sense the fan speed)
4. PWM (used to control the fan speed)

[image: fan connectors]

Your case has a basic fan controller built in - with a 3-position switch to set the speed.

> #### Fan Controller
>
> The fan controller is located in the top right corner behind the front door. The controller has three positions: the bottom position is the low speed (5v), the mid position is medium speed (7v) and the top position is full speed (12v).

---

> some curiosities, such as no internal speaker

Internal Speakers are not common anymore. Motherboards will either:

- Have an on-board piezo buzzer
- Will be shipped with a piezo buzzer on a wire
- Not have a speaker or buzzer

Comment: I was first but you win with all these details. +1.

Comment: I understand creating a good answer takes time, plus I have enough reputation; so no hard feelings on my side. Keep up the good work.

Comment: any idea why theres 3 of these male  connectors and only 2 female fan connectors on the case? Surely they dont intend connecting the cpu fan?

Comment: @theotherone - I would trace the cables to their source in order to answer that question.

Comment: As @Ramhound suggests... follow the cables. I would expect the 2x female connectors to lead directly to fans, while these 3x male connectors are probably fed from a single Molex or similar... I would _not_ recommend connecting the CPU fan to one of these 3x, but this allows for additional case (or other) fans.